# Why does Haskell's type system have a problem with my use of readFile?

Tags: parsing, haskell, types, readfile

I have some troubles with Haskell's type system.

Situation:

- Following program is taking list of filenames on the command-line
- For each filename its contents is read using the function `readFile`
- Contents of each file is passed to `inputParser` (from *Parsec* library)
- Rest is not so important
- Main problem is in function `read_modules`
- First two statements of the `do` expression are invalid in Haskell's type system
- Problem is conflict between `[String]` vs `IO String` vs `[Char]` vs ...
- Function `parse` should take a `String` but when it gets it, it wants an `IO String` suddenly (as the same argument), otherwise it wants a `String`

What do I want:

1. Read each file's content
2. Pass that content to the `parse` function as third argument

Here is the code:

```
module Main where

import System.IO
import System.Environment
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import InputParser
import Data

usage :: IO ()
usage = putStrLn "Usage: x file file file option"

parse_modules :: String -> [Char] -> Either ParseError [Module]
parse_modules filename input = parse inputParser filename input

read_modules :: [String] -> [Module]
read_modules [] = []::[Module]
read_modules (filename:rest) =
  do
    content <- readFile filename -- HERE is the problem
    modules <- case parse_modules filename content of -- HERE is problem too
      Left error -> do
        putStr "parse error at "
        print error
      Right out -> out ++ (read_modules rest)
    return modules

use :: [String] -> IO ()
use args =
  do
    init <- last args
    filenames <- take (length args - 1) args
    modules <- read_modules filenames
    return ()

main :: IO ()
main = do args <- getArgs
          if length args < 2
            then usage
            else use args
```

Here are the errors GHC outputs:

```
ghc --make -o x.hs input-parser.hs data.hs
[3 of 3] Compiling Main             ( x.hs, x.o )

x.hs:19:4:
    Couldn't match expected type `IO String'
           against inferred type `[String]'
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression: content <- readFile filename
    In the expression:
        do content <- readFile filename
           modules <- case parse_modules filename content of {
                        Left error -> do ...
                        Right out -> out ++ (read_modules rest) }
           return modules
    In the definition of `read_modules':
        read_modules (filename : rest)
                       = do content <- readFile filename
                            modules <- case parse_modules filename content of {
                                         Left error -> ...
                                         Right out -> out ++ (read_modules rest) }
                            return modules
-- THIS ERROR is somewhat not important
x.hs:30:4:
    Couldn't match expected type `[Char]'
           against inferred type `IO Char'
      Expected type: String
      Inferred type: IO Char
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression: init <- last args
    In the expression:
        do init <- last args
           filenames <- take (length args - 1) args
           modules <- read_modules filenames
           return ()
make: *** [x] Error 1
```

What is the problem:

- I cannot understand what I should pass where - I kind of know what I want, but I don't get the syntax or the style.
- I am new to Haskell.
- Haskell's types...

What are the questions:

- How do I fix the presented type issue?
- What should I put into `parse` - what `readFile` gives me?
- Are the types compatible?
- Isn't there need for some type of conversion?

Relevant weblinks:

- http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html
- http://www.zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/readFile_f.html
- http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell/2002-November/010748.html

Thank you all for your hints and comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what's causing the other error that you said was less important:

```
use :: [String] -> IO ()
use args =
  do
    init <- last args
```

The `<-` operator is used within a `do` block to extract something contained in a monad (in this case, `IO`) so that you can work with the actual value trapped inside. But, `args` here is of type `[String]`, not `IO [String]`, so you don't need to do that; you already pulled the argument list out of `IO` with `arg <- getArgs` in main.

If you want to assign a non-monadic value to a temporary variable inside a `do` block, use `let` instead, like this:

```
let x = last args
```

It looks like you're making the same mistake in several other places as well, not just that line. Having to treat monadic vs. non-monadic values differently like that, when you just want to make a temporary variable inside your function, is an easy thing to get confused about for someone new to the language.

By the way, `init` is the name of a function in the standard library, so you might want to use a different variable name.

Comment: Your answer isn't exactly what I wanted to hear, but after I have read something more about monads and <- operator I did understand many flaws in my code. Thank you for pointing to the true problem.

Comment: When it comes to simple functions in `IO`, it might help (for now) if you think about `<-` as "making it happen". Something with type `IO [String]` represents the idea of "doing some I/O and receiving a list of strings". Once you extract the value with `<-`, you've done the actual input and now you have your list, so you shouldn't be using another `<-` unless you want to be getting *more* input.

Comment: Though, as a caveat to my previous comment, that's definitely an oversimplification so don't take it too literally.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, since your function `read_module`s performs I/O it must return something of type `IO`. That means that you have to change a number of things in your function:

1. The empty case must use `return`
2. The `Right` branch in the case expression must use do-notation
3. When calling itself recursively the function must do so within the do-notation

Here's a (hopefully) fixed version of your `read_modules` function:

```
read_modules :: [String] -> IO [Module]
read_modules [] = return []
read_modules (filename:rest) =
  do
    content <- readFile filename -- HERE is the problem
    modules <- case parse_modules filename content of -- HERE is problem too
      Left error -> do
        putStr "parse error at "
        print error
      Right out -> do 
        more <- read_modules rest
        return (out ++ more)
    return modules
```

I haven't tested it but I hope it will help you on the way.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the IO. That was the major mistake.

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong.

```
read_modules :: [String] -> [Module]
```

Should be

```
read_modules :: [String] -> IO [Module]
```

That is not all that you need to fix, but it will get you going.